# How to move an object diagonally and in zigzag?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I created an algorithm to move a particle diagonally and it works fine using an angle. Basically, this is what I do:

```
this.x += this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
this.y += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
this.draw();
```

How can I combine this with a zigzag movement?

Comment: You could try varying the angle using `Math.sin(Date.now())` or something similar.

Comment: @SeanLeBlanc this makes the angle change, but I can't make it greater and smaller over time. this just changes abruptly every new draw

Answer (score 2):

I recommend calculating the lateral deviation from the normal path or `amplitude` which is given by

```
// Triangle wave at position t with period p:
function amplitude(t, p) {
  t %= p;
  return t > p * 0.25 ? t < p * 0.75 ? p * 0.5 - t : t - p : t;
}
```

where `t` will be set to the length of the traveled path, and `p` is the period of the 'zigzag' triangle wave pattern.

Given the amplitude and the previous position, we can now easily compute the next position by moving ahead as described by your original code and then adding the lateral deviation to our position:

```
  var amplitude = amplitude(distance, p) - this.amplitude(previous_distance, p);
  this.x += amplitude * Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI/180);
  this.y -= amplitude * Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI/180);
```

A complete example with two movable objects, one moving 'normally' and one following a 'zigzag' pattern:

```js
function Movable(x, y, speed, angle, period) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speed = speed;
  this.angle = angle;
  this.period = period;
  this.distance = 0;
}

Movable.prototype.moveDiagonal = function() {
  this.distance += this.speed;
  this.x += this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
  this.y += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
}

Movable.prototype.amplitudeZigZag = function() {
  var p = this.period, d = this.distance % p;
  return d > p * 0.25 ? d < p * 0.75 ? p * 0.5 - d : d - p : d;
}

Movable.prototype.moveZigZag = function() {
  var amplitude1 = this.amplitudeZigZag();
  this.moveDiagonal();
  var amplitude2 = this.amplitudeZigZag();
  
  var amplitude = amplitude2 - amplitude1;
  this.x -= amplitude * Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI/180);
  this.y += amplitude * Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI/180);
}

Movable.prototype.draw = function(context) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(this.x, this.y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.stroke();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var m1 = new Movable(0, 0, 2, 0, 50);
var m2 = new Movable(0, 0, 2, 0, 50);

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  m1.angle += Math.cos(i * Math.PI/180);
  m2.angle += Math.cos(i * Math.PI/180);
  m1.moveDiagonal();
  m2.moveZigZag();
  m1.draw(context);
  m2.draw(context);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Good solution. You may want to use the triangle wave function `f(t) = abs(4 * (t - floor(t + 1/2))) - 1` where t = time and has a frequency of 1 and amplitude range of -1 to 1. And a very minor point, the transform function is upside down compared to the 2D API. To match its `x -= sin(a)*d; y += cos(a)*d` and thus would be consistent with `ctx.rotate(a);ctx.translate(0,d);`

Answer (score 0):

So let's say that you're moving in the direction `this.angle` and you want to zig-zag in that direction moving side to side ±45° from that direction.  All you need to do is have a variable like `var zigzag = 45;` and add `zigzag` to `this.angle` when calculating the new positions.  And to make it zig-zag, you need to negate it every so often like this `zigzag *= -1;`.  If you want to stop zig-zagging, set `zigzag = 0;`.

The trick is knowing when to alternate between ±45°.  Maybe you can have the switch timed and keep a reference to the last time you switched using `Date.now();`.  You can check the difference between the current time and the recorded time, then negate `zigzag` once you've surpassed a certain number of milliseconds.  Just remember to record the new time of the last switch.  You could also keep track of distance travelled and use the same approach, whatever works for you.